# How do I get these two mesh parts to twist and meet each other at a single edge?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, topology, surface-deform

The two pieces on the right side of the image have different normals, and I  want the top curve of the B to gradually turn into the bottom part. I've tried simple deform and SimpleBend but haven't found an efficient way to do this. I want a few faces at the top to stay in place and the rest to rotate little by little.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to rotate the last edge with proportional editing activated?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe *Bridge Edge Loops* will do the job for you?

[image]